# Differential of a canonical map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, grassmannian, tangent-bundle

While studying about curvatures I came up with the following but was unable to work it out fully. Let $M \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be an embedded submanifold of dimension $k$. Then there is a natural (smooth?) map
$$\alpha: M \rightarrow \text{Gr}(k,\mathbb{R}^n),$$

given by $p \mapsto T_p M$. I know the grassmanian admits a natural description of its tangent spaces, namely:
$$T_V\text{Gr}(k,\mathbb{R}^n) \cong \text{Hom}(V , V^+)$$

where by $V^+$ I mean the orthogonal complement. Is there a nice description of its differential at an arbitrary point $p$? I couldn’t work it out. Also, a closesly related question: suppose we look instead of at $p \mapsto T_pM$ at $p \mapsto (T_p M)^+$, in the codimension 1 case, I think the differential + a choice of normal vector field gives you a bilinear form on $T_pM$ automatically. Intuitively I would expect this is something like the second fundamental form of the manifold , but again, when trying to work it out it becomes a mess. Any ideas? Thanks!

P.S. If someone knows a universal property the grassmanians satisfy, I’m also very interested!

Comment: "Is there a nice description of this map?" Which map are you referring to? You already described the map $\alpha$.

Comment: sorry I edited it

Comment: [A duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756197/derivative-of-gauss-map-is-the-second-fundamental-form#comment7726404_3756197)

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, but the other post does not have an answer ...